# how to search 1 cell in range of cells

Tags: excel, search, if-statement

I need a formula that will search if "A4" is in a range of cells (D column ~ 400 values) and write YES or No to B4. I need this to test over 1000 cells in A column by dragging the formula down the Colum manually.

This is a simple request, but I seem to be missing something.

Comment: You're talking about excel, right?

Comment: You can use `lookup()` to get info from a range, or you can use `countif()` or `countifs()` to count the number of ocurrences in a range based on specific conditions

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry to hear that. What happened to the old one?

Answer (score 3):

Put this in `B4` and drag / drop as you need:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($D$1:$D$400,A4)>0,"YES","NO")
```

Obviously, change the range for the D cells as is necessary.

Hope this does the trick